# phonegap android datepicker plugin cancel button doesnt hide dialog

Tags: java, android, cordova, datepicker

I have been able to port an old phonegap datepicker plugin to work with phonegap 3.0.0 and its new command line feature.
However after datepicker is triggered and the cancel button is tapped the datepicker disappears and reappear. The datepicker only disappears if a date is set.
Am not really good with java, so i dont where to begin to fix this issue

The java class can be found here at this [repo](https://github.com/mrfoh/cordova-datepicker-plugin)
Thanks for the help